# How to plot an NxN array of circles?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to plot an NxN array of circles. Just to visualize, I attached an image of what I want to achieve. I'm new in MatlLab so I tried to plot a single circle first, and here is the sample code below:

```
n = 2^10;                   % size of mask
M = zeros(n);
I = 1:n;
x = I - n/2;                % mask x - coordinates
y = n/2 - I;                % mask y - coordinates
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);      % create 2-D mask grid
R = 200;                     % aperture radius
A = (X.^2 + Y.^2 <= R^2);   % Circular aperture of radius R
M(A) = 1;                   % set mask elements inside aperture to 1
imagesc(M)                  % plot mask
axis image
```

I really don't have any idea on how to plot a 2D-array of circles. The distance between two circles is two radii. I need this for my research. Hoping anyone can help.[A 4 x 4 array of circles.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahtWR.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to plot a set of circles, you can use the [rectangle](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html) function within a loop

If in the call to `rectangle`you set the `Curvature` property to `1` it will be drawn as circle (ref. to the documentation).

In the loop you hav to properly set the position of each rectangle (circle) by defining its `lower left` coordinates along with its `width` and `height`.

Having defined with `n` the number of circles and with `d` their diameter, you can compute the set of `lower left` coordinates as:

```
px=linspace(0,d*(nc-1),nc)
py=linspace(0,d*(nr-1),nr)
```

The black background can be either obtained by setting the color of the axes or by plotting another rectangle.

Then you can set the `xlim` and `ylim` to fit with the external rectangle.

You can also make the axex invisible, by setting its ○Visible`property to`off`.

**Edit #1**

Code updated to allow drawing a user-defined number of circles (set the number of rows and the number of columns)

```
% Define the number of circles
% Number of rows
nr=8
% NUmber of column
nc=8
% Define the diameter of the circle
d=6
% Create an axex and set hold to on
ax=axes
hold on
% Evalaute the lower left position of each circle
px=linspace(0,d*(nc-1),nc)
py=linspace(0,d*(nr-1),nr)

% Plot the background rectangle
rectangle('Position',[px(1),py(1),d*nc,d*nr],'Curvature',[0 0],'facecolor','k')
% Plot all the circles
for i=1:length(px)
   for j=1:length(py)
      rectangle('Position',[px(i) py(j) d d],'Curvature',1,'facecolor','w')
   end
end
% Set the aspect ratio of the axes
daspect([1 1 1])
% Set the XLim and YLim
xlim([px(1) d*nc])
ylim([py(1) d*nr])
% Make the axes invisible
ax.Visible='off'
```

[image]

**Edit #2**

Aternative solution to address the OP comment:

*If I want to make the axes fixed, say I want a meshgrid of 1024 by 1024, (the image size is independent of the circle radius) how do I incorporate it in the code?*

If you want to use a fixed `(1024 x 1024)` mask on which to plot the circles, starting from the cde you've posted in the question, you can simply do the following:

- define the number of circles you want to plot, on a `(1024 x 1024)` mask they can be `2, 4, 8, ...`
- define a basic mask holding just one circle
- identify the points inside that circle and set them to `1`
- Replicate (using the function [repmat](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) the basic mask accoding to the numner of circles to be plotted

The implemntation, based on your code could be:

```
% Define the number of circles to be plotted
% on a (1024 x 1024) mask they can be 2, 4, 8, ...
n_circles=4
% Define the size of the basic mask
n0 = (2^10)/n_circles;
% Initialize the basic mask
M0 = zeros(n0);
% Define the x and y coordinates of the basic mask
I = 1:n0;
x = I - n0/2;
y = n0/2 - I;
% Create the mask
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
% Define the radius of the basic circle
R = n0/2;
% Get the indices of the points insiede the basic circle
A = (X.^2 + Y.^2 <= R^2);
% Set basic mask
M0(A) = 1;
% Open a FIgure
figure
% Replicate the basic mask accoding to the numner of circles to be plotted
M=repmat(M0,n_circles,n_circles);
% Display the mask
imagesc(M)
% Set the axes aspect ratio
daspect([1 1 1])
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have to save it as a bmp file. So when I used your code and saved the output figure as bmp file, the result had a white border on the actual figure. Anyhow, your code did what I asked. Thanks!

Comment: @VironGilA.Estrada.  you should be able to save just the axis as an image like this.   `fr = getframe(gca);
imwrite(fr.cdata, 'circle.bmp')`

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! Now I can make progress in my research.

Comment: Last question. What if I adjust the number of circles, say from 4 by 4 to 8 by 8 ,what should I change in the code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: ve updated the code to allow drawing a "user-defined" number of circles. Just set the variables nr to defihe the number of rows and nc to define the number of columns. You can use the solution proposed by @AeroEngy to save the figure as .bmp

Comment: If I want to make the axes fixed, say I want a meshgrid of 1024 by 1024, (the image size is independent of the circle radius) how do I incorporate it in the code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've further updated the answer in order to adress your last comment: ref. to the _Edit #2_ section at the bottom of the answer, below the picture.