# Store and plot two structures in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, data-structures, struct, cell

I am working with structures that two of which are shown below; **A** and **B**. I need to store **A** and **B** in a way (possibly not using tables) that allows MATLAB to plot them similar to the images.

[image: Structures]

Comment: Please see also [this related question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661413/compressing-decompressing-strings-matlab?noredirect=1#comment88334693_50661413). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my viewpoint, generating a sparse matrix and store the circles in it may be a solution. Here is a function which could generate a circle array in a sparse matrix with given structure & color. What you need is design a table which denotes the color of each item (0 means there a nothing in that position).

Function CircleArrays.m

```
function [Imgout] = CircleArrays(DataIn,r,s)
%%Draw a circle array with given colors 
% Parameters:
% DataIn ---- structures & color
%   r    ---- the radius of each circle
%   s    ---- the sparsity of the data
% Demo:
% S=rand(10);
% r=20;   
% sparsity=1; 
% Img=CircleArrays(S,r,sparsity);
% figure()
% colormap(hot)
% imagesc(1-Img)
% axis equal
% axis off

%Define a pre-allocate sparse matrix
[m,n]=size(DataIn);
Imgout=spalloc(m*(2*r+1),n*(2*r+1),floor(n*(2*r+1)*m*(2*r+1)*s));

%Create the Mask
I = 1:(2*r+1);             % Define the x and y coordinates of the basic mask
x = (I - r)-1;
y = (r - I)+1;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);      % Create the mask
M = (X.^2 + Y.^2 <= r^2);   
[xx,yy]=ind2sub(size(M),find(M == true)); 

%%Add circles into the matrix
for ii=1:m
  for jj=1:n
    if (DataIn(ii,jj) == 0) 
      continue;
    else
      MidX=(ii-1)*(2*r+1)+r+1;
      MidY=(jj-1)*(2*r+1)+r+1;
      Imgout(sub2ind(size(Imgout),MidX+xx-r-1,MidY+yy-r-1))=DataIn(ii,jj);
    end
  end
end

end
```

DEMO:

```
clc; clear;
%%Structures & configs
% define structures & color
S=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 .6 0.6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;];
%set the radius of each circle and the sparsity of the data
r=20;   
sparsity=0.25; 
%generate the Structures
Img=CircleArrays(S,r,sparsity);

%%Draw the picture
figure()
colormap(hot)
imagesc(1-Img)
axis equal
axis off
```

1. output by DEMO code:
   [image]
2. output by DEMO code in the function:
   [image]

Notes: I wrote this function based on [one of my old answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49009688/make-a-2d-array-of-circles-with-a-distance-of-2-radius-from-each-centers/49011253#49011253), so the circle mask maybe not 100% perfect, you can change it to whatever you like.

Comment: Check [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729623/how-to-plot-an-nxn-array-of-circles) may help, too.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this type of definition would not work for my application. It is a great solution, but since I am dealing with millions of these structures, the memory cannot handle that. I need to find a more compact way. Thanks, again

Comment: Neither do CPU times. I recommend you to edit and explicit the problem so others will give an adequate answer. @Amin

Comment: I think I found a way actually, but now I have another problem which I have posted here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661413/compressing-decompressing-strings-matlab?noredirect=1#comment88334693_50661413)